# Why is an incorrect size reported on multi-partition USB flash drive?

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning, mount, df

I'm creating a custom Linux installer which uses two partitions on a 4GB USB flash drive: an EFI partition for booting and a data partition for installer files.

The size reported by `df` is unexpected.

```
parted --script /dev/sdb -- \
    mklabel gpt \
    mkpart primary fat32 2048s 200M \
    name 1 EFI \
    set 1 boot on \
    set 1 esp on \
    mkpart primary fat32 200M 100% \
    name 2 MYDATA


# Format second partition
mkfs.vfat -F 32 -n DATA /dev/sdb2

# parted /dev/sdb p
Model: SanDisk Cruzer (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 4005MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name    Flags
 1      1049kB  200MB   199MB   fat32        EFI     boot, esp
 2      200MB   4003MB  3803MB  fat32        MYDATA
```

So far so good.  Now try mounting `sdb2` :

```
# mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/usb
# df -h
Filesystem                                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0                                      1.8G  4.0K  1.8G   1% /mnt/usb
```

`df` reports the size is only 1.8G. Further, it says the mount point is `/dev/loop0`.  Why?

Trying to mount with the exact partition offset gives different results:

```
# parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) unit b
(parted) p
Model: SanDisk Cruzer (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 4004511744B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start       End          Size         File system  Name    Flags
 1      1048576B    200278015B   199229440B   fat32        EFI     boot, esp
 2      200278016B  4003463167B  3803185152B  fat32        TORQUE  msftdata

# mount /dev/sdb /mnt/usb -o offset=200278016
# df -h
Filesystem                                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0                                      3.6G  4.0K  3.6G   1% /mnt/usb
```

Why is the size different? Why `loop0`? If the drive has only a single partition, `df` shows `/dev/sdb1` as the mount point, not `loop0`

**EDIT I**

[Kamil's](https://superuser.com/users/432690/kamil-maciorowski) suggestion to try `ls -l /dev/sdb*` was a good one. Somehow `/dev/sdb2` was replaced with a file, probably from a script bug.
That explains the size reported by `df` and explains why `mount` showed `loop0` as the source and not `/dev/sdb2`

```
$ ls -l /dev/sdb*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8, 16 Mar  3 08:48 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk      8, 17 Mar  3 08:48 /dev/sdb1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1912131584 Mar  2 21:37 /dev/sdb2
```

After removing the file `/dev/sdb2` `mount` and `df` worked correctly.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /dev/sdb*`?

Comment: What is the full `findmnt` and `df` output in this situation?

Comment: Kamil, that was a good hint.  `/dev/sdb2` was a file, not a block device. Must be from a bug in some script.  After deleting `/dev/sdb2` and mounting, `/dev/sdb2` was again a normal block device. Mounting and `df` showed the correct info!

Answer (score 2):

Initial answer:

- `/dev/loop0` is not the mountpoint. That's `/mnt/usb` – the mountpoint is where the filesystem is attached. The first column is the "source".
- Multiple filesystems can be mounted on the same location (same mountpoint). They stack instead of replacing each other. Only the latest mount (top of the stack) would be accessible in practice, but all "underneath" mounts remain in place and continue to be visible in `findmnt` and similar.
- The systemd manager, in some versions, will quietly auto-unmount filesystems that do not correspond to an /etc/fstab entry. For example, if your /etc/fstab says that device A is to be mounted on /mnt/foo, but you try to mount device B at the same path, the mount will succeed but get quickly unmounted the next second. This was a design issue within systemd that I *think* has been fixed in the current release, but it was long-lasting.

  That is to say, even though a mount command succeeded, it is still possible that its effects were immediately undone, and what you're looking at *isn't* the same mount you just did.

So what I'm currently guessing is:

0. You had /dev/loop0 (a squashfs image?) mounted on /mnt/usb.
1. You then manually mounted /dev/sdb1 on the same /mnt/usb. This only stacks on the existing mount but doesn't remove it.
2. Systemd immediately unmounts /mnt/usb because of the aforementioned bug. This removes the topmost mount and reveals the original mount from /dev/loop0 that was underneath.
3. Your `df` command now sees the original mount from step 0. The difference in filesystem size is moot because the whole device is not the same.

Use `findmnt --poll` to verify this. Have it running in one terminal (and maybe also `journalctl -f` in another), then retry the mount command.